# Problem passing JSON to stored procedure in SQL Server

Tags: json, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have this stored procedure:

```
CREATE TABLE ReportsPerFund 
(
    id INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    fundId INT NULL,
    reportId INT NULL
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
)

CREATE PROCEDURE [updateReportsPerFund] 
    @pJson nvarchar(max)
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO ReportsPerFund (fundId, reportId)
        SELECT fundId, reportId
        FROM OPENJSON(@pJson, '$.reportsPerFund')
        WITH (fundId int, reportId int)
END
```

When I call it like this it works:

```
updateReportsPerFund N'{"reportsPerFund":   [{"fundId":413, "reportId":1}]}';
```

But if I pass the string to a parameter and then use it to call the stored procedure, it fails:

```
DECLARE @tjson nvarchar(max) = N'{"reportsPerFund": [{"fundId":413, "reportId":1}]}';
updateReportsPerFund @tjson
```

There is no specific error.

I'm trying to pass a json to a stored procedure, and insert the values into a table

Comment: Have you tried the right property names? e.g.: `fundId` in OPENJSON != `idFund` in JSON.

Comment: Sorry, I already edited the post, that was something that I fixed... but as I said, when I pass the string directly it works, but if I assign the string to a variable fails...

Comment: Are you sure you're not getting an error message? `Incorrect syntax near 'updateReportsPerFund'.` Have you tried using the `exec` keyword?

Answer (score 0):

The exec clause is not mandatory, you can put just the name of the SP followed by the parameters it receives... The problem was solved when the server was restarted, and the query remained the same, later I decided to use a table type for performance. Thanks a lot for your comments.